# Saving multiple records in cakephp using datasources

Tags: cakephp-2.0

Is there a way to use saveAll() with a datasource in Cakephp 2.0? I've been able to successfully use save(), but saveAll() triggers an error.

Comment: Please specify what error you get and show us some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use the saveAll with the datasource. You should have to pass the array like:

```
   $data = array([0] => array(
                                [ModelName] = array(
                                                    [fieldName] => value1,
                                                     ...
                                                    )
                             )
                   [1] => array( ............
                   ..............
                   )
```

Then if you use $this->ModelName->saveAll($data), you will be able to save multiple records at once. And also if you pass an option " 'deep' => true " then you will be able to save multiple records in multiple related tables.

```
$this->ModelName->saveAll($data, array('deep' => true));
```